# Deserialize hibernate json column based on a column value

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jackson

I have a MySQL table that looks like this

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | name    | type  | properties                                            |
| 1   | nameA   | A     | {"prop_a1" : "value_1", "prop_a2": "value_2"}   |
| 2   | nameB1  | B     | {"prop_b1" : "value_3"}                         |
| 3   | nameB2  | B     | {"prop_b1" : "value_4"}.                        |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
Class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
}

Class EntityA exends BaseEntity {
 String prop_a1;
 String prop_a2;
}

class EntityB extends BaseEntity {
 String prop_b1;
}

class ParentEntity<T extends BaseEntity> {
 Integer id;
 String name;
 Enum type;
 T properties;
}
```

I am trying to keep polymorphic objects in the properties column, based on the Type column.
Tried using `JsonTypeInfo`, while it is able to write into the MySQL table but while reading it fails with error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field`

Has anyone tackled this use-case before?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare abstract getter and setter methods on `ParentEntity` and declare the persistent attribute in the subclasses.